# Excel 2003 copy worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two xls files: file1.xls and file2.xls

I want to copy the contents of sheet1 of the file "file1.xls" into sheet2 of the file "file2.xls".

Comment: Turn on the macro recorder and and copy from sheet1 of of file1 to sheet2 of file2. Turn off the macro recorder. The generated code won't be perfect, but it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim alpha As Workbook, beta As Workbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\alpha.xlsm"
    Set alpha = ActiveWorkbook
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\beta.xlsm"
    Set beta = ActiveWorkbook
    alpha.Sheets(1).Copy Before:=beta.Sheets(1)
End Sub
```